# Borrow value from HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

Still in my learning of rust while trying to make an ECS, I ecountered this issue :

I'm having a hashmap as a component table, where the keys are components ids and values are components arrays. Components array is a wrapper around another hashmap, where keys are entity ids and values are the components (so components arrays are generics with the type of component).

Here is the structure :

```
pub struct ComponentTable {
    components: HashMap<u32, Box<dyn ComponentArrayOnly>>,
}


pub struct ComponentArray<C> {
    comp_array: HashMap<u64, C>,
}

impl<C> ComponentArray<C> {
    pub fn new() -> ComponentArray<C> {
        return ComponentArray {
            comp_array: HashMap::new(),
        };
    }
}

trait ComponentArrayOnly {
    fn add_component(self, entity_id: u64);
}

impl<C: Component> ComponentArrayOnly for ComponentArray<C> {
    fn add_component(mut self, entity_id: u64) {
        if !self.comp_array.contains_key(&entity_id) {
            self.comp_array.insert(entity_id, C::new());
        }
    }
}
```

(the trait component array only is to hide the generics in the component table)

Now, when I try to add components from the component table, which should check if the component array exists (if not, add it) then call the add_component method on the array, I'm getting an error :

```
impl ComponentTable {
    pub fn new() -> ComponentTable {
        return ComponentTable {
            components: HashMap::new(),
        };
    }

    pub fn add_component_to<C: Component + 'static>(mut self, entity: u64) {
        if !self.components.contains_key(&C::id()) {
            // add a new component array
            self.components.insert(C::id(), Box::new(ComponentArray::<C>::new()));
        }
        // add the component at the entity id in the component array
        match self.components.get(&C::id()) {
            None => println!("Unable to add component : component array was not created !"),
            Some(c_arr) => c_arr.add_component(entity),
            //                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            // error[E0507]: cannot move out of `**c_arr` which is behind a shared reference
            // move occurs because `**c_arr` has type `dyn ComponentArrayOnly`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really understand what is going on. I don't want c_arr to be a shared reference, I would like to borrow it to modify it with add_component then release it back in the hashmap.

I looked the [HashMap documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) but couldn't find anything to achieve this.

Am I missing something? or is just poor design choices?

Comment: Your issue is that all your methods take `self` by value, i.e. move `self` into the method. Have you looked at Rust's [ownership semantics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) yet?

Comment: @isaactfa Yes, I've read most of the book a few weeks ago. 
How can I not use self ? Isn't here to let me use the values of my structs ? 
I've used to OOP, so I don't really see how a function could add a components to the array without borrowing the ComponentArray struct itself.

Comment: That's precisely the issue. You're not _borrowing_ the `ComponentTable`, you're _taking it by value_. To borrow it, and in your case you'll need to borrow it mutably, your methods needs to take `&mut self` not `mut self`.

Comment: And for the actual issue of getting access to the `HashMap`, you'll need to call `self.components.get_mut`.

Comment: @isaactfa Couldn't believed it was this simple. I thought that in rust, the "mut self" of the method would be references, not copies. Thanks, I'll answer the question !

Comment: Careful, taking by value _is not the same as taking a copy_. You would be _moving_ `self` into the method, making the method its owner and leaving the original owner of `self` uninitialized and unusable. The only values implicitly copied on a move are `Copy` types. I would suggest re-reading the ownership chapter of The Book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, the issue was that I was getting the ComponentArray by value and not reference when adding components to it.

So I needed to slightly change the implementation of add_component on the component array :

```rust
trait ComponentArrayOnly {
    fn add_component(&mut self, entity_id: u64);
}

impl<C: Component> ComponentArrayOnly for ComponentArray<C> {
    fn add_component(&mut self, entity_id: u64) {
        if !self.comp_array.contains_key(&entity_id) {
            self.comp_array.insert(entity_id, C::new());
        }
    }
}
```

And borrow the component array as a mut from the hashmap :

```rust
        match self.components.get_mut(&C::id()) {
            None => println!("Unable to add component : component array was not created !"),
            Some(c_arr) => c_arr.add_component(entity),
        }
```